# TFS project migration Utility

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration

Hi can any one suggest tool for migrating from TFS to TFS preferred Open Source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TfsToTfsMigration.codeplex.com has a toolkit and source available and is active, but then you knew that...

Comment: yeah i knew that its creating problem in tagging the branchs

Comment: Well, all the source is there. Obviously it's a non-trivial task to acutally do any interesting migration.  I'd also recommend mailing the contacts for tfs2tfs - they respond pretty quickly and will be able to give you roadmap info or point out other offerings in the space that might match your reqs.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating what - builds, source, labs/vm's, work items?

For workitems my favorite way to do it is to open two instances of excel, one connected to each of your TFS projects.
Select the same set of fields in your query.
Copy all items from the one Excel into the other.
Then click Publish on the other.